# org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl cannot be cast to org.hibernate.SessionFactory

Tags: hibernate

I am upgrading one of our applications from jboss 4.0.5 GA to Jboss 7.1.1, and I am encountering the exception below:

org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl cannot be cast to org.hibernate.SessionFactory

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl cannot be cast to org.hibernate.SessionFactory

My persistence.xml is:

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

```
<persistence-unit name="XXModelPU">

    <description>XXModelPU</description>

    <jta-data-source>java:/GTDB</jta-data-source>

    <properties>

        <property name="hibernate.session_factory_name" value="java:/hibernate/GTDSessionFactory"/>

        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />

        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />

        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"/>

        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="false"/>

    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

Hibernate3 was used for the development of the application.

Kindly help figure out what the issue is...

it is giving a java.lang.NullPointerException in the line of code below:

```
java.util.List applicationList = new HibernateUtil().loadObjects("GraphicsHelper");
```

my loadObjects method is given below:

```
 public List loadObjects(String ObjectName) {
    Query sqlQuery = null;
    List objectList = null;
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        tx = currentSession().beginTransaction();
        sqlQuery = currentSession().createQuery("from " + ObjectName);
        objectList = sqlQuery.list();
        tx.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (tx != null) {
            tx.rollback();
        }
        ExceptionManager exmgr = new ExceptionManager();
        exmgr.processException(e, "Error in loadObjects() for HibernateUtil class");
    } finally {
        closeSession();
    }
    return objectList;
}
```

The classcast issue is being flagged in my HibernateUtil constructor, the constructor is given below:

```
public HibernateUtil(){
    try{

        if(sessionFactory == null){
            javax.naming.InitialContext ctx = new javax.naming.InitialContext(); 
             sessionFactory = (SessionFactory)ctx.lookup("hibernate/GTDSessionFactory");
        } 
    }catch(Exception e){

        ExceptionManager exmgr = new ExceptionManager();
        exmgr.processException(e , "Error while looking up hibernate sessionfactory in HibernateUtil class");

    }
}
```

*************Monday, October 13 2014 -- 07:47:33 AM***************
Error in loadObjects() for HibernateUtil class
ERROR MESSAGE:    null
java.lang.NullPointerException

*************Monday, October 13 2014 -- 07:52:34 AM***************
Error while looking up hibernate sessionfactory in HibernateUtil class
ERROR MESSAGE:    org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl cannot be cast to org.hibernate.SessionFactory
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl cannot be cast to org.hibernate.SessionFactory

*************Monday, October 13 2014 -- 07:52:34 AM***************
Error while looking up hibernate sessionfactory in HibernateUtil class
ERROR MESSAGE:    org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl cannot be cast to org.hibernate.SessionFactory
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl cannot be cast to org.hibernate.SessionFactory

Comment: Please can you add the stack trace you are getting and the code snippet that the stack trace refers to?

Comment: I have updated my question, kindly help..

Comment: Which exception are you getting? You mention both a null pointer exception and a class cast exception in your question. Also, please can you post the stack trace of the exception? Thanks.

Comment: I have updated my question. The issue is that it is the class cast that is the root cause of the null pointer exception because the constructor is unable to assign value to the sessionfactory that is to be used in the loadObjects() method, the method sees the sessionfactory as null, then it flags it...resolving the class cast issue is the main thing that I need solution for..

Comment: I suspect this may be a classloader issue caused by having the Hibernate jars in two places - one for JBoss, and again in the application. If the global resource definition for the Hibernate session factory is loaded by the JBoss container classloader, whereas the HibernateUtil code is part of your app, this could cause the class cast exception. Hence some things you could try to fix this are: 1. Removing the session factory property from your persistence unit. 2. Removing the Hibernate jars from the app. 3. Defining the session factory property in the app, not at the global level.

Comment: if I remove the session factory it will be giving nameNotFound error. Actually I know that one of the issue is that of jar conflict, because I bundled hibernate3.jar with my application and hibenate 4.x is bundled with AS7, if i replace hibernate3 in my app with 4.x, some methods that I used e.g .connection() are no longer available in 4.x. I have exhausted all the options you give already...what else do you think I can do?

Comment: You best option might be to update your code to use 4.x and then remove the hibernate 3 jar from the app. Why are you calling connection()? If you just need to run SQL, then you should call createSQLQuery instead.